# Firebase permission: Create links

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to integrate Firebase with Crashlytics for my app. When I click the "Link apps" button on the Fabric / Firebase linking page, I get a *Unable to create link, you do not have the required Firebase permissions to create links* error.

The question is: **exactly what kind of permission is needed?** (I've got editing privileges - I'm not the owner of the project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Firebase and Fabric here. You need to be an owner in Firebase and an admin/owner within Fabric in order to set up the linking flow.

Comment: I have admin permission and able to migrate a few applications from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics. But for two iOS applications, we are getting "Linking error" which says "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)". Can you help me out with this?

Comment: I'd contact the Fabric support team at support(at)fabric(dot)io.